# Conversion failed when linking tables via unique ID and right function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to link our audit history tables against our main data tables in our system.

With the following query:

```
select distinct *
from main.StudentAttendanceRoll sar
join main.student st on st.id = sar.StudentId
join audit.AuditEntity ae on right(ae.AuditEntityId, 27) = sar.id
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

`ae.AuditEntityId` has a value of

> /AppSchema=Main/EntityType=StudentAttendanceRoll/Id=7d4787a3-606d-ea11-80eb-000d3ae0232d

where as `sar.id` has a value of

> 7D4787A3-606D-EA11-80EB-000D3AE0232D

Would expect this to be a straight forward join. Not sure why it's failing.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: Sorry for wasting people's time, although I'd love to delete this out of embarrassment on how basic my error was (if I had triple checked what I had done, I would havent needed to ask) thought it wise to leave the post here as a good lesson on being more methodical. Thanks @Dale K :)

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results as formatted text.

Comment: Hi Dale

Sorry I'm still new to stackoverflow and SQL so please bear with me, as basic questions still going over my head.


ae.AuditEntityId has a value of '/AppSchema=Main/EntityType=StudentAttendanceRoll/Id=7d4787a3-606d-ea11-80eb-000d3ae0232d'

where as sar.id has a value of 
'7D4787A3-606D-EA11-80EB-000D3AE0232D' . Would expect this to be a straight forward join. Not sure why it's failing.

Not sure about 'formatted text' apologies in advance. Tried to look at the help links regarding it.

Comment: [edit] any improvements into the question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - see further down for formatting text.

Comment: You need to produce a [mre] for us, else we can't offer anything over the error you already have.

Comment: the fact you need to cast to compare 2 GUIDs means your design  is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked what `right(ae.AuditEntityId, 27)` returns you? It definitely won't be a uniqueidentifier, count the characters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply `RIGHT function with 36 for uniqueidentifier'. As right side, it is uniqueidentifier, in the left side also, you need to cast the datatype as uniqueidentifier to make the comparison working.

You don't need to cast varchar value to uniqueidentifier, as datatype precedence takes care of implicit conversion to higher datatype. [Reference datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
use tempdb
go
DECLARE @querystring VARCHAR(1000) = '/AppSchema=Main/EntityType=StudentAttendanceRoll/Id=7d4787a3-606d-ea11-80eb-000d3ae0232d'
DECLARE @guid2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '7D4787A3-606D-EA11-80EB-000D3AE0232D'

IF RIGHT(@querystring,36) = @guid2
select 'equal'
else
select 'not equal'
```

**Note:** Uniqueidentifier is restricted to 36 characters. so, if you are having length > 36 characters, result will be truncated. [Refer Uniqueidentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(max) = N'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong';  
SELECT @ID, CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, @ID) AS TruncatedValue;
```

| String | TruncatedValue |
| --- | --- |
| 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0wrong | 0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0 |

Comment: @Ry--9 are you sure? Have you tried changing `right(ae.AuditEntityId, 27)` to `right(ae.AuditEntityId, 36)` as suggested? You are truncating your guid, you are asking for 27 characters, but that is not enough to store a guid, hence it will never match a guid. It doesn't get any simpler than that I'm afraid... if you `select right(ae.AuditEntityId, 27)` from a few rows of your table you'll see what is happening. Btw 1 downvote isn't anything to get excited about... we've all had them. Its just (or can be) a motivation to improve.

Comment: @Ry--9, yes. from your sample data, you have to use `RIGHT(ae.AuditEntityId, 36)` to make them match

Comment: @Dale K....... Ok, so I deserved to be downvoted actually! I'll blame sleep deprivation, many windows on my browser open but the big one that I VERY stupidly called the wrong column. Very embarrassing. Thanks for the extra nudge and dealing with my initial discouragement. Will be more methodical in future....lesson learned :)